How would I change a PdfFormField on a duplicated PdfPage without affecting the original PdfFormField using itext7 in C#?
Using the itext7 library in .NET, I am duplicating a page of a PDF Document in order to add more emails to the duplicated page and then append the duplicated page directly after the original page. Currently I can't wrap my head around how to get the PdfFormField objects on the duplicated page in order to rename and edit the value of those fields.
PdfPage copy = pdf.GetPage(9);
pdf.AddPage(9, copy);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);

// This will set the email field on original page 9 and duplicated page 9 to test@email.com
form.GetField("Email0").SetValue("test@email.com");

// This only returns one PdfFormField object
var field = form.GetField("Email0");

I tried searching for a method within the PdfPage class that would allow me to access the form fields from there but did not find one. I tried adding the new page to the current PDF, getting the PdfAcroForm and then attempting to use GetField/GetAllFormFields but am still not seeing two "Email0" fields.

@k-j In that case do you recommend utilizing a blank PDF as a secondary template to copy the PdfPage to, edit the field names/content on that blank PDF, and then merging with the destination PDF? I had envisioned editing the fields on the PdfPage object initially, but it seems that isn't an option unless I am missing documentation. Thank you!
